# Why gif image do not animate in modeless window?

Tags: c#, wpf, gif

To show animated GIF in WPF/C# I use this code sample in Microsoft MSDN : [Show GIF animation in WPF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWPFAnimatedGIF-3029aeb9).

When I use this in modeless window (`window.Show()`), the image do not animate. Why?

With `window.ShowDialog()` (modal window) it works correctly.

In WPF Project Befor Start MainWindow i show a window to do my first task in modeless and then close it.(these are in app.xaml.cs Startup event)

```
// app.xaml.cs 
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstTask firstTask = new FirstTask();
        firstTask.Show();

        // do task
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        firstTask.Close();

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I add below code end of AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded function in AnimatedGIFControl class to start animate gif automatically.

ImageAnimator.Animate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);

complete AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded code

```
     void AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get GIF image from Resources
        if (gifanimate.Properties.Resources.ProgressIndicator != null)
        {
            _bitmap = gifanimate.Properties.Resources.ProgressIndicator;
            Width = _bitmap.Width;
            Height = _bitmap.Height;

            _bitmapSource = GetBitmapSource();
            Source = _bitmapSource;
            ImageAnimator.Animate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
        }             
    }
```

ImageAnimator.Animate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);

Also i add  to firstTask window and MainWindow to show animated gif.

Another problem: after firstTask.Close(); application do not show MainWindow. did you know why?

Comment: I downloaded that example and added extra form for it (as startup window), with 2 buttons - one will start mainWindow with Show method and other with ShowDialog. Both of them runs correctly. Can you describe your problem little more detailed?

Comment: You will have to lose the Sleep() call, nothing can animate while your UI thread is catatonic.  Use a timer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show() method does not block the call and continues with the execution,

ShowDialog() method blocks the call and waits with the execution until the modal dialog is closed (and also during that,all UI messages are dispatched)

Answer (score 0):

I fond a solution for that.

// app.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    private FirstTask firstTask;

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker backWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backWorker_DoWork);
        backWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        firstTask = new FirstTask();

        firstTask.ShowDialog();

        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    void backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        firstTask.Close();
    }

    void backWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

I use BackgroundWorker to do my tasks in background. after complete tasks close firstTask and show mainWindow.

important attention: For showing mainWindow after closed first task, mainWindow should declare before firstTask.ShowDialog().